# jsPDF working on first save, not updating on second in IE

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to generate PDF from HTML using jSPDf and Html2Canvas.js, the code is working fine in Chrome but in IE it works fine first time, while generating PDF, second time the controls are overlapping and aligned to one side of PDF.

Please provide the solution to generate the correct image on second submit click

```
function generateCanvas() {
  pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
  html2canvas($('#div1')[0], {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var contentWidth = canvas.width;
      var contentHeight = canvas.height;
      var pageHeight = contentWidth / 592.28 * 841.89;
      var leftHeight = contentHeight;
      var position = 0;
      var imgWidth = 595.28;
      var imgHeight = 592.28 / contentWidth * contentHeight;
      var pageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      console.log(pageData)
      if (leftHeight < pageHeight) {
        pdf.addImage(pageData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 700, 900);
      } else {
        while (leftHeight > 0) {
          pdf.addImage(pageData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
          leftHeight -= pageHeight;
          position -= 841.89;
          if (leftHeight > 0) {
            pdf.addPage();
          }
        }
      }
      pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE? What error(s) are you getting in the console?